# Injection of a SLF4J Logger - only injects once

Tags: java, cdi, slf4j, openwebbeans

I am wanting to inject a `org.slf4j.Logger` into classes that need it instead of declaring it as static at the top and specifying the class name eg.

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
```

To do so I have created a producer method like so

```
@Produces
public Logger getLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint)
{
    return LoggerFactory.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
}
```

And then I inject it using `@Inject` but it only seems to do inject for the first class that requests it, all other classes that have a `org.slf4j.Logger` injection point end up with a NPE

Comment: I do use the described logic and it is working, could you provide a minimal (non) working example for your case?

Comment: trying to create a short non working example for you and failing at the moment :(

Comment: Yeah, that is why a short code sample would be nice ... Because the given code snippet looks OK, hence the problem must be elsewhere in the usage.

Comment: You may want to provide some basic info like what does your runtime look like, container, java version, etc.

Comment: Why would you want to use @Inject for loggers?